# How to merge data from two text file

Tags: java, text, merge

I have two related text files shown for example in data1.txt and data2.txt. I want to merge the two files to create result.txt. Any idea how to go about this?

data1.txt

```
books, 3
Shelf, 5
groceries,6
books, 1
Shelf, 2
```

data2.txt

```
books,2
shelf,3
groceries,1
```

result.txt

```
books, 3, 2
Shelf, 5,3
groceries,6,1
books, 1,2
Shelf, 2, 3
```

Comment: read line one by one from both ,then split finally combine

Comment: I tried reading line by line but it does not work because the order of data2 is not the same as data1

Comment: why 4th line of result.txt is "books, 1,2" ??

Comment: the corresponding value for books in data2.txt is 2.

Comment: I had a project just like this a couple weeks ago, sure I can help. Question tho, I notice that some of these arrangements are a bit different, I see that some of the commas have spaces after them, others don't, is that a mistake or is that what we should expect?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper that is a mistake. There should be no spaces after the commas.

Comment: you need to store lines in 2d arraylist for mapping values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a example for you.first you need to add values to `2d list` from data2 text file.and then when line is null in file2 you can get mapping value relative to it's text from that list .so i have a method which will return back the mapping value for a String .code is little long than i thought .i post only relevant methods here.[This is link to complete class file](http://pastebin.com/KKyeCynz)

```
public void marged(){
    try {
        BufferedReader br1 = null;
        BufferedReader br2 = null;

        String line1;
        String line2;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Madhawa.se\\Desktop\\workingfox\\data1.txt"));
        br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Madhawa.se\\Desktop\\workingfox\\data2.txt"));

        while ((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] split1 = line1.split(",");

            String line1word = split1[0].trim();
            String line1val = split1[1].trim();

            line2 = br2.readLine();

            if (line2 != null) {
                String[] split2 = line2.trim().split(",");

                String line2word = split2[0].trim();
                String line2val = split2[1].trim();

                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
                list.add(line2word);
                list.add(line2val);
                arrayList.add(list);

                if (line1word.equalsIgnoreCase(line2word)) {
                    String ok = line1word + "," + line1val + "," + line2val;
                    System.out.println(ok);
                }

            } else {
                String ok = line1word + "," + line1val + "," + doesexist(arrayList, line1word);
                System.out.println(ok);
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is the method return mapping value

```
public String doesexist(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayList, String s) {

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        String get = arrayList.get(i).get(0);
        if (get.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(s.trim())) {
            return arrayList.get(i).get(1);
        }
    }
    return "-1";
 }
```

output>>

```
books,3,2
Shelf,5,3
groceries,6,1
books,1,2
Shelf,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add files into an array of `File` object then read it using loop.

```
File []files = new Files[amountOfFiles];
//initialize array elements
for(File f:files)
{
      //read each file and store it into string variable
}

//finally write the string variable into result.txt file.
```

Comment: This will work if only the order of the data in data1 and data2 are the same. that is book,shelf,groceries. What if data2 is arranged this way: shelf,book,groceries

Comment: @FreeMan the user knows in which sequence he wants to store the data into resultant file so he will add the data according to requirement. Nobody would like to hard code again and again to store new file name into newer object by creating it.

Comment: I understand your point. I think I need to reframe the question. so assuming data1.txt is your main file. records in data1.txt has unique identifiers stored in data2.txt. how will you assign to each item in data1.txt the identifiers in data2.txt. Hope it makes sence. this is why in the result.txt, books have the same identifier, 2

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class SOQ21
{

   public SOQ21()
   {

      merge();

   }

   public void merge()
   {

      try
      {
         String firstfile = "data1.txt";
         FileReader fr1 = new FileReader(firstfile);
         BufferedReader bfr1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);

         String secondfile = "data2.txt";
         FileReader fr2 = new FileReader(secondfile);
         BufferedReader bfr2 = new BufferedReader(fr2);

      /*
      ^^^ Right here is how you get the files and accompanying BufferedReaders 
      to handle them
      */

      //next, using the readLine() method from the Java API, read each line
      //for the first file

      //then, separate by taking the words into an ArrayList and storing the
      //numbers as Strings in a String[] of equal length of the ArrayList


      //Do the same for the second file

      //Then, if the word of ArrayList 1 matches the word of ArrayList 2, 
      //append the String numbers from String[] 2 to String[] 1

      //DONE! :)

      }

      catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
      {

      //handle how you want

      }


   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      SOQ21 soq = new SOQ21();

   }

}
```

The comments I made should answer most of your questions. Lastly, I would pay special attention to the exceptions, I'm not entirely sure how you wanted to deal with that, but make sure you fill it with **SOMETHING!**